# Hi, can anyone explain about why we need to generate a token in sonar qube? Its mandatory or not? if its mandatory can you explain it why?

Tags: sonarqube

can anyone explain why we need to generate a token in sonarqube ? Its mandatory or not? if its mandatory can you explain it why?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

Tokens allow you (in reality the scanner engine) to connect to the SonarQube server without having to reveal any user credentials. If you bind SonarQube to an external authentication source (Active Directory, LDAP, OAuth) then a token prevents you having to create a generic user in that authentication source and/or revel authentication details.

With a token the access is also limited to a specific project so the leak of a token prevents impact to other projects, which the leak of a username and password may not.

Tokens are required when connecting to a non-local (i.e. not on loopback network) SonarQube instance.